# Pycharm: where are the python packages?

Tags: python, pycharm

I just reinstalled my Pycharm and I don't see any packages. They are used to be in Setting/Interpreter. But now, it keeps showing loading.
[image]

Comment: The packages are installed in site-packages, if pycharm shows error when you try to import them, then try to make a new project or restart pycharm. If it doesn't show error, then they must have been installed , so don;t worry

Comment: yes, i can also istall them without error. However, when I last used pycharm, there were a list of packages, but now, it just says "loading".  what is happening?

Comment: Did you wait some time, before to check interpreter? Look bottom left corner. On first runs PyCharm takes times to find and load packages and symbols. BTW: try to use a separate environment for each projects. It really help (e.g. to reset env. conda and Pycharm sometime do no like some upgrades).

Comment: Contact PyCharm support at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com and send them `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...**